# How to set multiple task to single button

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a button that needs to do one task when it presses and another task when it tapped again. As an example let thing I have a floating menu when I  first tapped it. it should expand all menu then after I tapped it again it should collapse it how to do this in xamarin forms

Comment: bool as a member variable that flips your "mode"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a flag.

```
private bool _isFirstTime = true; // Class level
public bool IsFirsttime = true;   // Application level
```

use this at class for current use, at application level if you need to rember during app's life cycle or save it as parameter.